# Store hex printf output to variable

Tags: c, hex, decimal, rounding

I have to round off a float to decimal. After rounding off, I should convert this number to hexadecimal. I think I got the round off part okay with `round()`

Is there a way to convert a decimal to hexadecimal in C, and store it into a part of an array? 
I'm thinking of the concept on how `printf()` converts the decimal to hex.

What I have in mind is something like this:

```
float k = 10.123;
int a;
unsigned char var_store[1];
unsigned char array_t[3];
array_t[0] = 0x01;
array_t[1] = 0x04; 
a = round(k);
var_store[0] = sprintf("%x",a);
array_t[2] = var_store[0];
```

but I'm having a

> warning passing argument 2 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast

I'm not sure if this is the way to do it. But I think this is relatively straight forward. Thanks

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this, and you can do it with sprintf. But you are using sprintf incorrectly. Did you read the documentation for sprintf?

Comment: The last two lines in your code imply that you need to go to the basics of the language (or at least think what it is exactly that you want to do). No offense of course.

Answer (score 2):

People tend to get very confused with the term "hexadecimal". It should mean "the number as a human-readable ascii string with digits 0-F", but because raw binary data is typically presented in hex, people miuse it to mean the binary data itself.
Whilst of course you can write a function that converts a decimal number, expressed as a string, to a hexadecimal number, expressed as another string, it's fiddly and, except as a learning exercise, pointless thing to do. sprintf converts C variables to human-readable strings for you. To get a decimal, pass "%d", to get hex, pass "%x". You also need to pass a destination buffer, like this.

```
char destination[256];
int a = 123; 
sprintf(destination, "number is decimal %d hex %x", a, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not recollect any library function.

But the traditional mathematical way is below. I you want you can create a user defined function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int decimalNumber = 2567888;
    char hexadecimalNumber[100];
    int temp;
    int i =1;

    while(decimalNumber!=0)
    {
         temp = decimalNumber % 16;

      //To convert integer into character
      if( temp < 10)
           temp =temp + 48;
      else
         temp = temp + 55;

      hexadecimalNumber[i++]= temp;
      decimalNumber = decimalNumber / 16;
    }

    for(int j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
      cout<<hexadecimalNumber[j];
}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std; ... cout<<hexadecimalNumber[j];` does not compile as  C as this post is tagged  Perhaps you are thinking of another language?